# How to remove space or "nextline" in front of date in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am working on an excel with more than 60,000 rows of data. There is a column with date but sometimes there is space or "nextline" in front of the date. How do I remove these? I cannot work on the data until I can clean this up, thanks!

Comment: [How to use the "Find and Replace" dialog box in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288291])

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a new column with this formula

`=IF(ISTEXT(A1),TRIM(A1),A1)`

Then manually change the formatting to date.

Comment: I just try, same as the result of trim, it will become a number and cannot convert back to date.

Comment: for example, 3/6/2010 becomes 40243, then how do I convert this number back to date? Thanks.

Comment: this is a sign that you did it correctly ... when a date text is converted to a numbera, Excel recognized it as a valid date string ... a date **is** a number in Excel ... you may use a date cell format to display it correctly

Comment: I tried to just change the format to date, but the number doesn't change or update.

Comment: entering 40243 in a cell, right clicking it, [Format Cells...] -> Date changes display to 06.03.2010 (according to my local date format)

Comment: I find out a way. After changing it to number, then cannot directly convert it to date. Have to copy and paste to another column and paste with only number, then choose to change to number. Then can be converted back to date.

Comment: Because change the format of the cell =SUBSTITUTE(E2," ","") doesn't work.

Comment: @Teemo I edited the answer, now you should be able to change to format to make it work

Comment: If you just use `find and replace`, then you wouldn't have these problems.

Answer (score 0):

It contain CR so ...

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,chr(10),"")
```